# Trouble logging in and/or changing password

Tags: login, password

I have tried to log in to my WordPress site using my username and the password that has been on the account since the beginning, but I have not been able to log in.

I have tried to reset the password. When I click on the link in my inbox, it takes me to a WP page that says "Sorry, that key does not appear to be valid" and redirects me to: http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&error=invalidkey. I also have spent countless hours on the phone with GoDaddy (they are hosting it).

I am in desperate need of help to log into my blog. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the methods on this page: [Resetting Your Password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password)?

If you have FTP access or access to phpMyAdmin via your hosting control panel, you could try either of those options.